# Thymeleaf: Use the text content as default if the message resolver fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've recently started using i18n with Thymeleaf and Spring 4, as such:

```
<span th:text="#{foo.bar}">Foo Bar</span>
```

Is there any way to make Thymeleaf actually display "Foo Bar" if the `foo.bar` key does not exist for the user's locale?

This is the current configuration I have:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/messages/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true); // anything equivalent?
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The useCodeAsDefaultMessage property of the message source is a last resort for preventing an exception in abscence of the code mapping. (If the MessageSource cant find your code mapping it throws a NoSuchMessageException). It is there for development and debugging, so in general there is no clean way to do this because it is not a good practice to use message codes not defined somewhere.

Comment: Why I'd like to do this is to simply use the English language as a default, as defined in the Thymeleaf template and let the message codes override it with `th:text` if the user wants a locale which we support. Is there nothing like this?

Comment: A good i18n approach is to also externalize your English messages, i.e place them in a properties file without locale extension, which will be picked as default if no locale related version is present.  The text in Thymeleaf html pages is mainly for prototyping.